# How to convert number with leading zero like 043562 to string '043562'

Tags: javascript

How to convert number with leading zero like 043562 to string '043562'?

If I use toString() it is giving me wrong output.
It is working fine for number without leading zero for example :

```js
const number = 043562;
const number2 = 435622;

console.log(number.toString()); //output: 18290, expected output : 043562
console.log(number.toString(8)); //output: 43562, expected output : 043562
console.log(number2.toString()); //output: 435622
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal numbers. To convert a number with leading zeros to a string, you can use the padStart() method of the string object.

Check example code below:

```js
const number = 43562;
const str = number.toString();
const paddedStr = str.padStart(6, '0');
console.log(paddedStr); // Output: '043562'
console.log(typeof paddedStr); // Output: 'string'
```

In this example, we first convert the number to a string using the toString() method. Then, we use the padStart() method to add leading zeros to the string until it has a length of 6 characters. The second argument to padStart() is the character to use for padding, which in this case is the string '0'.

Tell me if this was helpful to you.

Comment: here you have used five digit number "const number = 43562". incase if the number starts with 0. do we need to remove 0 and follow the above steps?

Comment: No. It will automatically keep the length to 6 characters. If you enter 043562 as the number, it will give you '018290' as output. If you try increasing the '0' Infront of number, it will not change since we gave max for 6 characters. You can even try yourself to check will it give you the expected outcome.

@mplungjan I used it to generate an explanation to this code and I will not do that again. Thank you.